# WPF - modify RadFilePathPicker properties when used as a RadPropertyGrid Editor Attribute

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I have a [RadFilePathPicker](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radfilepathpicker/getting-started) as a [RadPropertyGrid editor attribute](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radpropertygrid/features/editor-attribute)

The RadFilePathPicker is defined as a property attribute as follow:

```
[Telerik.Windows.Controls.Data.PropertyGrid.Editor(typeof(RadFilePathPicker), "FilePath")]
public string HtmlSourceFile { get; set; }
```

I would like to set the RadFilePathPicker ReadOnly property to false (default is true), however, the RadFilePathPicker is created from the RadPropertyGrid control and thus have no access to modify its properties.

Is there a way to modify the RadFilePathPicker properties ? perhaps by settings a xaml template for the whole window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a built in option for that. Either add an [implicit style](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/styling-and-appearance/styling-apperance-styling-the-controls) targeting `RadFilePathPicker` and set `IsReadOnly` to false, or subscribe to the `FieldLoaded` event of `RadPropertyGrid` and set `(Field.Content as RadFilePathPicker).IsReadOnly` to false.

Comment: Thanks, the style did not work for some reason but the field loaded was the solution

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in setting to do this when using the `EditorAttribute`.

As an alternative to the `EditorAttribute`, you can use the [EditorTemplate](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radpropertygrid/getting-started/gettingstarted-customized-property-definitions) property of the `PropertyDefinition`. This will allow you to adjust the `RadFilePathPicker` as desired.

Comment: Thanks, this probably works but the Zaphod solution was simpler to implement.